# Group under composition of functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $T(S)$ be the set of all functions on $S = \{1,2,3 \}$. Show that $T(S)$ is a group under composition of functions.

I am to prove that this is either true or not. I would like some help understanding exactly what the author means by *"group under composition of functions"*. And can you give me an example of a set of all functions on some other set?

Comment: You have a binary operation $T(S)\times T(S) \to T(S)$, namely the composition of functions. Does that operation make $T(S)$ a group?

Comment: When you write $ \times $ do you mean any operation or do you mean the multiplication (was it called multiplication?) of sets?

Comment: Is $S$ the range of functions as well?

Comment: The $\times$ is the Cartesian product, $T(S)\times T(S)$ is the set of ordered pairs whose components belong to $T(S)$.

Comment: To help clarify Daniel's point:  the binary operation $T(S) \times T(S) \to T(S)$ that may (or may not) give $T(S)$ the structure of a group is **composition**.  From a pair of functions $f, g \in T(S)$, form $f \circ g \in T(S)$.

Comment: @Spock: if the operation is composition, then the range has to be a subset of S.

Comment: Can someone explain real fast what it means to be "a group under multiplication"? Does that mean that for the operation $a * b = a \cdot b$ ?

Comment: Yes in that case group operation is multiplication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Test 0:**  Is the operation associative?  If not, then you're done.  $T(S)$ is not a group.  If the operation *is* associative, then proceed to...

**Test 1:**  Does the set $T(S)$ contains an identity?  If you have a candidate function in $T(S)$, then what equations must it satisfy?  Does it?  If not, then $T(S)$ is not a group.  If you *do* have an identity, then proceed to...

**Test 2:**  Does every element of $T(S)$ have an inverse?  Given an arbitrary function in $f \in T(S)$, can you write down its inverse $f^{-1} \in T(S)$?  What equation must $f$ and $f^{-1}$ satisfy?  (Hint:  you need the identity function.)  If any function fails to have an inverse, then $T(S)$ is not a group.  If every function *does* have an inverse, then..

**Congratulations!  Your set $T(S)$ is a group.**

Mouse over the box to reveal a hint.

> One of these tests fails, so $T(S)$ is **not** actually a group under composition.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sammy Black pointed out: 
Identity element in our case is the identity map but
Inverse element property fails in this case. Take the function $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=1$ then there's no function $g$ such that $fog=gof=identity~ map$